# The sequences of primes of the form $\,q_n=q_0+2(2^n-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a prime $\,q_0$, if $\,q_k=q_{k-1}+2^k$ is prime till $\,k=n$, that is if $\,q_m=q_0+2(2^m-1)$ is prime for $\,0\le m\le n$, we could define a function $\,\lambda\,$ such that:

$\lambda(q_0)=n\;\;$ if the above condition is verified;

$\lambda(q_0)=-1\;\;$ if not.

Obviously, if $\,q_0$ is the first of a pair of twin primes, then $\,\lambda(q_0)\ge1$. The values of $\,\lambda(q_0)$ for the first $25$ primes are: $\,-1, 1, 3, -1, 2, -1, 5, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1$.

Some extreme values: $\,\lambda(1607)=7$, $\,\lambda(19427)=8$.

**Is $\,\lambda(q_0)\,$ bounded?**

Many thanks.

Comment: So $q_1=q_0+2^1=q_0+2?$ That would mean that $\lambda$ being unbounded would imply that $q_0+2$ is prime for infinitely many primes $q_0$, which would be the twin prime conjecture, correct?

Comment: @Mastrem Yes, perfect.

Comment: Yes, but if the function gets arbitrarily large, then it is at least $1$ infinitely often. Or are you asking whether $\lambda$ is well-defined?

Comment: How many times is the prime gap series 2,4,8,16 mod 30  in a row ? If there is no upper $n$ value then it's unbounded, otherwise it is...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee This sounds morally equivalent to prime $k$-tuples, just for a specific infinite set of tuples.  There’s no chance of proving or disproving such a claim, but we could easily verify that it satisfies the admissibility criterion.

Comment: To even be a leader $q_0\equiv 17 \pmod {30}$

Comment: As mentioned , a proof will already fail because of the twin prime conjecture. Should this conjecture be false, the given function would trivially be bounded. On the other hand there seems to be no reason that it cannot be unbounded. The best we can do is to find as large values as possible. Would you be content with values of , lets say , $20$ ? I find the question interesting (+1)

Comment: Interestingly  it can't be 197 mod 210

Comment: $$\lambda(2397347207)=9$$
$$\lambda(2407977827)=9$$

Comment: $$\lambda(153535525937)=10 $$
$$\lambda(627759496157)=10 $$
$$\lambda(844188769217)=10 $$